# get all store records even though filters applyed

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Is it possible that I can get all records even though the filters are apply to the store.
Please provide some guideline or reference code.

```
var spareStore = Ext.getStore('ABC');
spareStore.filter( 'item', value);
```

when I alert spareStore count it should be all rechords.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use snapshot property of store as :

```
var allRecords = store.snapshot || store.data;
```